# Box.com SDK for iOS: Checking authorization status

Tags: ios, box-api

The box.com SDK for iOS has an object called `sharedSDK` that holds another object called `OAuth2Session`. `OAuth2Session` has a property called `isAuthorized`. On each application launch this property is set to `NO`. Even if I keep the `refreshToken` inside the system Keychain, and assign it at launch like so:

```
//...applicationDidFinisLaunching...
NSString *token = [controllerObject fetchFromKeychainForKey:@"com.box.token"];
[BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.refreshToken = token;

if ([BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.isAuthorized) {
    //Not until signing in
    NSLog(@"Authorized.)";
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not Authorized.");
}
```

What should I be doing differently to check auth status? The Dropbox SDK has a method to determine if the session is linked, persists through launches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of the iOS SDK. The `isAuthorized` method is only a best guess of whether or not the current OAuth2 tokens are valid. From the [documentation](http://box.github.io/box-ios-sdk-v2/Classes/BoxOAuth2Session.html#//api/name/isAuthorized):

> Compares accessTokenExpiration to the current time to determine if an access token may be valid. This is not a guarantee that an access token is valid as it may have been revoked or already refreshed.

Because `accessTokenExpiration` is not stored anywhere by the Box iOS SDK, this field will be nil following initialization, even if the refresh token is loaded.

The Box iOS SDK takes the stance that the Box API is the source of truth about state and does not attempt to perform client side checks that can be handled more reliably by the server.

The recommended way of reloading the OAuth2 session is to set the refresh token from the keychain as you have done and then issue a "heartbeat" API call to trigger an autorefresh or fail if the refresh token is invalid.

An example of this can be found in the [Box iOS SDK sample app](https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-sample-app/blob/master/BoxSDKSampleApp/BoxSDKSampleApp/BoxNavigationController.m)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(boxAPIAuthenticationDidSucceed:)
                                                 name:BoxOAuth2SessionDidBecomeAuthenticatedNotification
                                               object:[BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(boxAPIAuthenticationDidFail:)
                                                 name:BoxOAuth2SessionDidReceiveAuthenticationErrorNotification
                                               object:[BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(boxAPIInitiateLogin:)
                                                 name:BoxOAuth2SessionDidReceiveRefreshErrorNotification
                                               object:[BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session];

    // attempt to heartbeat. This will succeed if we successfully refresh
    // on failure, the BoxOAuth2SessionDidReceiveRefreshErrorNotification notification will be triggered
    [self boxAPIHeartbeat];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)boxAPIHeartbeat
{
    [[BoxSDK sharedSDK].foldersManager folderInfoWithID:BoxAPIFolderIDRoot requestBuilder:nil success:nil failure:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Handle OAuth2 session notifications
- (void)boxAPIAuthenticationDidSucceed:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Received OAuth2 successfully authenticated notification");
    BoxOAuth2Session *session = (BoxOAuth2Session *) [notification object];
    NSLog(@"Access token  (%@) expires at %@", session.accessToken, session.accessTokenExpiration);
    NSLog(@"Refresh token (%@)", session.refreshToken);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    BOXAssert(self.viewControllers.count == 1, @"There should only be one folder in the hierarchy when authentication succeeds");
    BoxFolderViewController *rootVC = (BoxFolderViewController *)self.topViewController;
    [rootVC fetchFolderItemsWithFolderID:BoxAPIFolderIDRoot name:@"All Files"];
}

- (void)boxAPIAuthenticationDidFail:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Received OAuth2 failed authenticated notification");
    NSString *oauth2Error = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:BoxOAuth2AuthenticationErrorKey];
    NSLog(@"Authentication error  (%@)", oauth2Error);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)boxAPIInitiateLogin:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Refresh failed. User is logged out. Initiate login flow");

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        NSURL *authorizationURL = [BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.authorizeURL;
        NSString *redirectURI = [BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.redirectURIString;
        BoxAuthorizationViewController *authorizationViewController = [[BoxAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithAuthorizationURL:authorizationURL redirectURI:redirectURI];
        BoxAuthorizationNavigationController *loginNavigation = [[BoxAuthorizationNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:authorizationViewController];
        authorizationViewController.delegate = loginNavigation;
        loginNavigation.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

        [self presentViewController:loginNavigation animated:YES completion:nil];
    });

}
```

This view controller registers for OAuth2 notifications which are triggered in the event of a successful refresh or a logout. In the selectors you register for these callbacks, you can load a view controller in your app or load the BoxAuthorizationViewController to log a user in.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I forgot about this question! I really like the SDK, thanks for getting it put together.

Comment: I am very frustrated with this SDK. I have done all of this, but I can't keep my user logged in. How do you use the refresh token on a UITableView to refresh the access tokens?

Comment: @Ryan Would you recommend putting the "heart beat" method in a timer loop to periodically fire (say, every 30 minutes)? I am building an app where the Box folder would only be accessed periodically, so there is a significant chance of the access token expiring.

Comment: Also, is there any reason we shouldn't be using `[[BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session performRefreshTokenGrant:refreshToken]`

Comment: From my tests, it seems running `performRefreshTokenGrant:` on a timer (every 20 minutes or so) is the only reliable way to keep the `accessToken` current. `folderInfoWithID:` does not actually update the token, so eventually (within an hour) it seems this would expire and there's no gaurantee the user won't be doing a "non-enqueueable action" at that time.